# Using std::vector in CUDA device code

Tags: cuda

The question is that: is there a way to use the class "vector" in Cuda kernels? When I try I get the following error:

```
error : calling a host function("std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > ::push_back") from a __device__/__global__ function not allowed
```

So there a way to use a vector in global section?
I recently tried the following:

1. create a new Cuda project
2. go to properties of the project
3. open Cuda C/C++
4. go to Device
5. change the value in "Code Generation" to be set to this value:
   compute_20,sm_20

........ after that I was able to use the printf standard library function in my Cuda kernel.

is there a way to use the standard library class `vector` in the way printf is supported in kernel code? This is an example of using printf in kernel code:

```
// this code only to count the 3s in an array using Cuda
//private_count is an array to hold every thread's result separately 

__global__ void countKernel(int *a, int length, int* private_count) 
{
    printf("%d\n",threadIdx.x);  //it's print the thread id and it's working

    // vector<int> y;
    //y.push_back(0); is there a possibility to do this?

    unsigned int offset  = threadIdx.x * length;
    int i = offset;
    for( ; i < offset + length; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] == 3)
        {
            private_count[threadIdx.x]++;
            printf("%d ",a[i]);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: +1 perfectly legit question (not sure why it was voted down.  Unfortunately the answer is currently no.

Comment: sorry for necroposting. Just wanna know if there is any answer to this right now

Answer (score 24):

You can't use the STL in CUDA, but you may be able to use the [Thrust library](http://developer.nvidia.com/thrust) to do what you want. Otherwise just copy the contents of the vector to the device and operate on it normally.

Comment: I don't see how this is supposed to help, because a `thrust::device_vector` cannot be used inside kernels, either.

Answer (score 14):

In the CUDA library Thrust, you can use `thrust::device_vector<classT>` to define a vector on the device, and the data transfer between host STL `vector` and `device_vector` is very straightforward. You can refer to [this](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/index.html) useful link to find some useful examples.

Note however, that `device_vector` itself can **not** be used in device code either. Only its pointers/iterators can be used there.

Answer (score 7):

you can't use `std::vector` in device code, you should use array instead.

Answer (score 6):

I think you can implement a device vector by youself, because CUDA supports dynamic memory alloction in device codes. Operator new/delete are also supported. Here is an extremely simple prototype of device vector in CUDA, but it does work. It hasn't been tested sufficiently.

```
template<typename T>
class LocalVector
{
private:
    T* m_begin;
    T* m_end;

    size_t capacity;
    size_t length;
    __device__ void expand() {
        capacity *= 2;
        size_t tempLength = (m_end - m_begin);
        T* tempBegin = new T[capacity];

        memcpy(tempBegin, m_begin, tempLength * sizeof(T));
        delete[] m_begin;
        m_begin = tempBegin;
        m_end = m_begin + tempLength;
        length = static_cast<size_t>(m_end - m_begin);
    }
public:
    __device__  explicit LocalVector() : length(0), capacity(16) {
        m_begin = new T[capacity];
        m_end = m_begin;
    }
    __device__ T& operator[] (unsigned int index) {
        return *(m_begin + index);//*(begin+index)
    }
    __device__ T* begin() {
        return m_begin;
    }
    __device__ T* end() {
        return m_end;
    }
    __device__ ~LocalVector()
    {
        delete[] m_begin;
        m_begin = nullptr;
    }

    __device__ void add(T t) {

        if ((m_end - m_begin) >= capacity) {
            expand();
        }

        new (m_end) T(t);
        m_end++;
        length++;
    }
    __device__ T pop() {
        T endElement = (*m_end);
        delete m_end;
        m_end--;
        return endElement;
    }

    __device__ size_t getSize() {
        return length;
    }
};
```

Comment: Even if it is correct, it is likely to be slow because of the memory allocation inside expand() function. Great effort though.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `std::vector` in device-side code. Why?

#### It's not marked to allow this

The "formal" reason is that, to use code in your device-side function or kernel, that code itself has to be in a `__device__` function; and the code in the standard library, including, `std::vector` is not. (There's an exception for `constexpr` code; and in C++20, `std::vector` does have `constexpr` methods, but CUDA does not support C++20 at the moment, plus, that `constexpr`ness is effectively limited.)

#### You probably don't really want to

The `std::vector` class uses allocators to obtain more memory when it needs to grow the storage for the vectors you create or add into. By default (i.e. if you use `std::vector<T>` for some `T`) - that allocation is on the [heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap). While this could be adapted to the GPU - it would be quite slow, and incredibly slow if each "CUDA thread" would dynamically allocate its own memory.

Now, you could say "But I don't want to allocate memory, I just want to read from the vector!" - well, in that case, you don't need a vector per se. Just copy the data to some on-device buffer, and either pass a pointer and a size, or use a CUDA-capable `span`, like in [`cuda-api-wrappers`](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers) or [`cuda-kat`](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-kat/blob/master/src/kat/containers/span.hpp).

Another option, though a bit "heavier", is to use the [NVIDIA thrust library](https://nvidia.github.io/thrust/)'s `device_vector` class. Under the hood, it's quite different from the standard library vector though.

Comment: `device_vector` can't be used in device code (its iterators can). By now there is an official implementation of `span` and `mdspan` in [libcu++](https://nvidia.github.io/libcudacxx/releases/changelog.html).

Comment: @paleonix : There is, but - I'm against `libcu++` as a project. NVIDIA should not try to replace the standard library, nor does it make sense for people to try and use the standard library on CUDA devices. Only some small pieces of it, which should not pretend to be the full thing.